# Setting woocommerce customer note through functions.php not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I'm trying to modify the Customer Order note to say "Ship with this provider" when a customer billing/shipping address is a specific city.

WordPress 5.2.2
WooCommerce 3.6.5

I'm using the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook, getting the order data via order ID and `get_customer_note()`, `set_customer_note()`.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou','route_mail_on_customer_location', 30, 1);

function route_mail_on_customer_location($order_id){
  $CP_cities = ["City 1", "City 2", "City 3"];

  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $curr_note = $order->get_customer_note();
  echo "<p>Customer note: " . $curr_note . "</p>";
  if((strpos($curr_note, "Ship with Canada Post.") == false) && (in_array($order->get_shipping_city(), $CP_cities, true))){
    $note = __($curr_note . ". Ship with Canada Post.");
    $order->set_customer_note($note);
  }
  echo "<p>Customer note: " . $order->get_customer_note() . "</p>";
}
```

The echo results display correctly.

```
Customer note: Test Note

Customer note: Test Note Ship with Canada Post.
```

When I check the order page the order note is only the original customer note.

```
Customer provided note:
Test Note
```

It looks like the setter isn't sending the changes to the database. Is there a method I need to call to make sure that my changes are added to the DB, or should I just do it directly via a wpdb query?

EDIT: Corrected echo results to reflect code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the follows code snippet to achieve to task -

```
function modify_woocommerce_checkout_posted_data( $posted_data ){

    $CP_cities = array( 'city1', 'city2', 'city3' ); // make sure to replace with proper city data

    $curr_note = $posted_data['order_comments'];
    if( strpos($curr_note, 'Ship with Canada Post.') == false  && in_array( $posted_data['shipping_city'], $CP_cities ) ){
        $note = $curr_note . __(' Ship with Canada Post.', 'textdomain' );
        $posted_data['order_comments'] = $note;
    }
    return $posted_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'modify_woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 99 );
```

Comment: Hey, I used this answer but I had to fix two things.

`if( !isset( $posted_data['order_comments'] ) ) return $posted_data;`

I removed this line because I still want a comment to be posted even if the user left the comment field empty.

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 99 );`

I don't think you can have the same function name, I changed the second function name here and the custom declared function to the same. 

If you fix those two things I'll checkmark this answer.

Thank you! This helped out a lot!

Comment: @aoa, yes you can do that but for your information, you can use same function name untill and unless the name is not used by others with that priority. And for your needs I'm changing my above codes.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 
'customer_note_email_after_order_table', 10, 4 ); 
function customer_note_email_after_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, 
$plain_text, $email ){

// Only on some email notifications
if ( in_array( $email->id, array('new_order', 'customer_on_hold_order', 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order') ) ) :

// Get customer Order note
$customer_note = $order->get_customer_note();

// Display the Customer order notes section
echo '<h2>' . __("Order notes", "woocommerce") . '</h2>
<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; color: #636363; border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;" border="0">
    <tr><td><p>' . $customer_note . '</p></td></tr>
</table></div>';

endif;

}
```